# load images into a numpy matrix array from a dataset and apply conversion

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I need to load images into a numpy matrix array from a dataset which contains 800 images of each being 64 by 64 pixels. I need to convert each 64 by 64 image into a row of the matrix which has 4096 columns. Below I have shown how I am approaching the code. I recieve a ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4096 into shape (64,). Please help thank you.

```
array = np.zeros((800, 64))

for i in range(800):
    path = “some path”
    img = mpimg.imread(path)
    array[i] = img.reshape(64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original array should be of shape `800, 4096`, since each sub-array represents a `(64, 64)` image, which requires 4096 elements.

Therefore, I think you want this instead:

```
array = np.zeros((800, 4096))
paths = [...] # set paths here

for i, path in enumerate(paths):
    array[i] = mpimg.imread(path).reshape(4096)
```